# Run Java program from C code

Tags: c, execvp

I'm looking for a way to launch a java application from C code
I read that in C you can launch external programs with **execvp(const char *pathname, char *const argv[])**.

So I made a test:

```
char *array[6];
array[0] = "java";
array[1] = "-jar";
array[2] = "myJar.jar";
array[3] = "10000";
array[4] = "/other/path/";
array[5] = NULL;

execvp("java", array);
```

The program starts, but the other parameters aren't set (**10000** and **/other/path/**). If I launch the program manually:

```
java -jar myJar.jar 10000 /other/path/
```

everything works fine. How can "translate" in C?
The machine is Ubuntu 14.10...

Comment: are you sure that this is your actual code? Everything looks fine

Comment: Yes, is correct....
This is my complete code:
`#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
  char *array[5];
  array[0] = "java";
  array[1] = "-jar";
  array[2] = "/var/servers/myServer.jar";
  array[3] = "10000";
  array[4] = NULL;
 
  execvp("java", array)
 return 0;
}`

Comment: no `/other/path` there?

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt, you FOUND solution!! :) I do not pass all the parameters and the application would not start!

Thanks!!!